# Equations of a projective toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, toric-geometry

Given complete fan $\Delta$ defining a projective toric variety (so that $\Delta$ is the normal fan of some polytope). How do one go on to find a defining ideal of the toric variety in projective space?
 Or, going the other way, given binomial equations defining a projective toric variety, is there some way to recover the fan?

In my case, I am trying to recover the fan of the hypersurface $Z(x_0x_3-x_1x_2)$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ ($n>3$).

Answer (score 13):

To get the equations, one way to find this is to read David Cox's *The Homogeneous Coordinate Ring of a Toric Variety*, which you can find [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9210008).

If you are given the equations *and* you know the action of the torus on the variety, you can reconstruct the fan by looking at the way orbits are placed relative to each other. I think this is explained in Fulton's book, for example.

Everything should be explained in Cox's new book (together with Little and Schenk), aptly named [*Toric Varieties*](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~dac/toric.html)

**Later.** Let's do your example with $n=4$. There is a simply transitive action of the torus $T=(\mathbb C^\times)^3$ on the subset $\mathcal T$ of your variety $X$ of those points all of whose coordinates are non-zero such that $$(t_1,t_2,t_3)\cdot(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3:x_4)=(x_0:t_1x_1:t_2x_2:t_1t_2x_3:t_3x_4).$$
The set of group homomorphisms $\mathbb C^\times\to T$ is parametrized by the abelian group $\mathbb Z^3$, with $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z^2$ corresponding to the map $$\chi_{a,b,c}:t\in\mathbb C^\times\longmapsto (t^a,t^b,t^c)\in T.$$
Now let $p=(1:1:1:1:1)$, a point in $%\mathcal T$, and the  consider the limit $$\lim_{t\to0} \chi_{a,b,c}(t)\cdot p=\lim_{t\to0}(1:t^a:t^b:t^{a+b}:t^c)$$ Depending on the value if $(a,b,c)$ in $\mathbb Z^3$, this limit changes (and in some cases may not exists). This determies regions in $\mathbb R^3$ where the behaviour does not change: these regions are the relative interiors of the cones in the fan.

For example, in the regions

1. $a>0, b>0,c>0$
2. $a<0, a+b>0, c>0$
3. $b<0, a+b>0, c>0$

the limits exist (and are $(1:0:0:0:0)$, $(0:1:0:0:0)$ and $(0:0:1:0:0)$, respectively) so this gives us three of the cones. You'll surely have fun determining all the rest :)